# How to open .pts (Pro tools) files in Mac without Pro Tools?

Tags: macos, pro-tools

Is there any way to open .pts files created in Pro Tools using an Open Source or a less expensive software?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Audacity, but you'll have to export all the tracks and make new projects. (It's a proprietary format.)